# Firebase Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.4.0', apply: false] was not found

Tags: flutter, firebase, visual-studio-code, build.gradle

I tried to add Firebase to my Flutter project but I get this error.

[image: tap to see error]

I see lots of solutions here on this error. But none of them had helped. On the Firebase documentation, along steps, there is no step to add a classpath. When an error occurred, I added it to `build.gradle` (project level) according to the solutions here. But the error is the same.

And to be clear, I want to share my `build.gradle` (project-level) file:

[image: codes] with you.

And also you can see in the below picture, the plugin part of `build.gradle`  (app-level) file:

[image: this picture]

Please, help me to solve that error.

Comment: Don't post [images for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2466342), use code blocks with mark down ``` instead

Comment: This issue was same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77284171/12346234) please check for more details.

Comment: @VincentGripo yes, this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

1.Add Firebase to Your Flutter Project:
Make sure you have added Firebase to your Flutter project by following these steps:
Go to the Firebase Console (https://console.firebase.google.com/).
Create a new project or select an existing one.
Add your app to the Firebase project by clicking "Add app" and select the appropriate platform (Android).
Follow the setup instructions, which will involve downloading a
google-services.json file.
Place this file in the android/app directory of your Flutter project.

2.Configure build.gradle Files:
Update the build.gradle files in your Flutter project as follows:

In your project-level build.gradle (usually located in android/build.gradle), make sure you have the Google Services classpath:

````
    // ...
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1' // or the latest version
}```

n your app-level build.gradle (usually located in android/app/build.gradle), add the following at the bottom of the file:
```apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'```
then after make these changes
run ```flutter pub get ```
and Double-check your dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml `
```dependencies:
  firebase_core: ^latest_version
  firebase_auth: ^latest_version
  firebase_database: ^latest_version
  firebase_messaging: ^latest_version```


3.Check google-services.json:
Ensure that the google-services.json file in your android/app directory is correctly configured for your Firebase project.

4.Clean and Rebuild:
Sometimes, issues can be resolved by cleaning and rebuilding the project. In Android Studio, you can find these options in the "Build" menu.
````