# Gradle Error: Plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' Version 4.4.0 Not Found

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build-error

I am facing an issue with my Gradle build where I'm getting an error related to the Google Services Plugin. The error message is as follows:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.4.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

What I've Tried:

1.) I've ensured that my build.gradle files are set up correctly (based on the firebase instructions). Here's a snippet for reference:

**build.gradle (Project: example)
**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false
}
```

**build.gradle (Module :app)
**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.example'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'

    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-chinese:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-devanagari:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-japanese:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition-korean:16.0.0'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'

    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:translate:17.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation project(':opencv')

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

}
```

**settings.gradle (Project Settings)
**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "example"
include ':app'
include ':opencv'
```

2.) I came across a similar issue on Stack Overflow: [Plugin com.google.gms.google-services version 4.4.0 apply: false was not found in any of the following sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284171/plugin-com-google-gms-google-services-version-4-4-0-apply-false-was-not-found-i?newreg=d63ac117d10c4a64a9d9387c95fc8753) and tried the solutions mentioned there. Unfortunately, none of these steps have resolved the issue.

Question:

Has anyone encountered this specific problem and found a solution? I'm looking for any insights or additional steps I can take to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to use the latest version of all libraries. As far as I can see, in the case of Google Services Gradle Plugin, the [latest version is currently 5.0.0](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/tree/master/google-services-plugin).

I have personally tried it, but I couldn't make it work due to the following error:

> Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '5.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

It's the same as in your case, but the version is different. However, when I used the `4.4.0` version everything worked as expected. I will share my dependencies with you:

build.gradle (Project file):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        gradle_version = '8.1.3'
        kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
        google_services_version = '4.4.0'
        compose_bom_version = '2023.10.01'
        compose_version = '1.5.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.library' version "${gradle_version}" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "${kotlin_version}" apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version "${google_services_version}" apply false
}
```

build.gradle (Module file):

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

dependencies {
    //Compose
    implementation platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:$compose_bom_version")
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material"
    //...
}
```

So in my case, worked with Kotlin version `1.9.10` and Gradle version `8.1.3`.

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this if you have

`apply plugin: "com.android.application"` in `android/app/build.gradle`

change

```
plugins {
  id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false
}
```

to this

```
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

also change other plugins with id, to `apply plugin:` style.